# Postgresql - how to convert bytea to text or string in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, serialization, bytea

I have a column that is bytea in postgres, and I can use a statement like this to get this kind of output:

```
select encode(mycolumn,'escape') from personTable;
```

and get:

```
254\355\000?sr\000?java.util.HashMap??\332\301\303?`\321?\000?F\000
loadFactorI\000 thresholdxp?@\000\000\000\000\000?w?\000\000\000?\000\000\000?t\000?      
userIdt\000
USER2200000x
```

How would I see this in plain text? It is indeed storing a java.util.HashMap-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a Java issue rather than a PostgreSQL issue. `personTable.mycolumn` is holding a byte-string that was created using the Java Serialization API, and to retrieve the original object that the byte-string represents, you need to use that same API. (See ["Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html) for sample code.)

Comment: ok, yup this makes sense, the application is saving serialized objects, i just didn't realize there wasnt a way to see the plain text in postgres. thanks!

Comment: How you solved the problem ? I also want to convert a bytea  of postgres to Java String. please see my question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-convert-bytea-to-text-value-in-postgres